# Convert NSString into executable statement

Tags: ios, nsstring

I am facing an issue with converting NSString into executable statement of objective C.

For example,

```
NSString *strColorAssembly = @"[UIColor redColor]";
```

Now, I need to convert this string into an executable code and pass to .color property.
This is just an example, I am trying to build a project in which everything will be dynamic, so It would be much helpful if anyone can provide me right direction to go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that on iOS, period. iOS prevents you from allocating memory pages that can both be written to and also executed.

The best you could manage is an interpreter that takes strings in, parses them, and attempts to map them to Objective-C calls (using `NSClassFromString` and `NSSelectorFromString`).

I would recommend not doing what you're trying to do, and instead use one of the many bindings from Cocoa to a dynamic language. I think the most popular ones bind Cocoa to Lua, so then you can write your Lua code and everything will be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can programmatically accomplish that goal. If it were me I would implement a method that accepted an NSString (or an NSInteger) and return a UIColor.

```
- (UIColor *)colorDecode:(NSString *)colorPassed
{
 if ([colorPassed isEqualToString @"red"])
 {
  return [UIColor redColor];
 }
 else if
 .
 .
 .
}
```

OR

```
- (UIColor *)colorDecodewithInt:(NSUInteger)colorIndex
{
 switch (colorIndex)
 {
  case (0)
  {
   return [UIColor redColor];
   break;
  }
  case (1)
  .
  .
  .
  .
  default
  {
   return <some default color>;
   break;
  }
 }
}
```

EDIT:
I suppose you could also use an NSDictionary that consists of a collection of UIColor objects as well. The bottom line is that you're going to be restricted to a pre-defined set of colors in your compiled code unless you start playing with CGColor at which point you can start dynamically pass the RGB values.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is the `setValue:ForKey:` method.  Anything that conforms to the NSKeyValueCoding Protocol will have that option available.  However, this will only work for the `key` part (i.e. the name of the property).  iOS explicitly prohibits any modification to the distributed code.  I would recommend using the `key`s as strings and writing some kind of interpreter for the rest of your data.

Comment: Sounds to me more like he's trying to write a parser and VM for Objective-C in Objective-C.